# I have created a Cloudtrail using terraform but it says I'm missing S3 bucket policy after deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

Here is my Cloudtrail code. I don't know how to create the S3 bucket policy for this. Can you please help me with the access policy that I need.

```
resource "aws_cloudtrail" "download_log_trail" {
    name = "download_log_trail"
    s3_bucket_name = sample
    enable_logging = true
    include_global_service_events = true
    is_multi_region_trail = true
    enable_log_file_validation = true

    advanced_event_selector {
      name = "Log download event data for individual S3 bucket objects"
      field_selector {
        field = "eventCategory"
        equals = ["Data"]
      }
      field_selector {
        field = "resources.type"
        equals = ["AWS::S3::Object"]
      }
      field_selector {
        field = "eventName"
        equals = ["GetObject"]
      }
      field_selector {
        field = "resources.ARN"
        starts_with = [""]
      }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bucket policy for CloudTrial is described in AWS Docs:

- [Amazon S3 bucket policy for CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/create-s3-bucket-policy-for-cloudtrail.html)

In terraform you can use [aws_s3_bucket_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_policy) to create the policy for the bucket associated with CloudTrial.